# Why the gene symbol aliases have significantly different sequences?

Tags: ensembl, identifiers, entrez

"Aliases" or "Synonyms" should represent the same gene but with different names. But when I try to find the sequence of one alias and try to match with another alias they are significantly different.

During bioinformatics analysis, I need to convert NAT5 alias ID to its gene symbol ID (NAA20, NAA50). When I tried to match the sequences of NAA20 and NAA50, they are very different but still NAT5 is an alias of both NAA20 and NAA50.

I have to convert one id to another id (ENSEMBL). These gene symbol and alias is so confusing.

I am looking for NAT5 and when I search for NAT5 in ENSEMBL, it shows both NAA20 and NAA50.

From UniProt the canonical sequence of both the proteins:

https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P61599#sequences

https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q9GZZ1#sequences

I am confused which one to chose?

Answer (score 5):

At Ensembl, we categorise synonyms as anything that a gene might also be known as. This includes older names for them, since those names will be in the literature, including where a gene has been split in two.

Answer (score 2):

*Answer from @devon-ryan, converted from comment:*

Both, that's why NAT5 is no longer a human gene symbol.

NAT5 does not equal NAA20, it's an out-dated name for it. Names change over time as people realize that there are more genes for something than originally thought.